# can't refresh page after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i put refresh code if condition success, but it's not run, i was replace with some code but,still not run

this is controller

```
if($result) {
$response = array(
                'success' => true,
                'message' => $this->localization->lang('success', array('name' => $this->localization->lang('task_tickets')))
            );
           $this->redirect->back();
        } else {
            $response = array(
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $this->localization->lang('error_update_message', array('name' => $this->localization->lang('task_tickets')))
            );
        }
```

and this is view of index

```
 function reject(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= $this->url_generator->current_url() ?>/reject/'+id,
            function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $.growl.notice({message: response.message});

                    } else {
                        $.growl.error({message: response.message});
                    }
                }
        })
```

Comment: `.ajax` parameter is not a proper Object, and does not have the correct properties, for starters.

Comment: Missing `success:`, you just have `function(){}`. Also, `$result` in PHP should be like `if(isset($_GET['prop1'])){ /* $paramVal = $_GET['prop1']; */ }`, but what are you sending with that `id` argument without `folder?prop1=val1&prop2=val2` format anyways?

Comment: in controller or view?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX works like so, if you're using the `.ajax` function, for a `$_GET` request:

```
$.ajax({
  method:'GET',
  dataType:'json',
  url:'wherever_you_send.php?prop1=val1',
  success:function(phpJSON){
    console.log(phpJSON.returnProp);
  }
});
```

Now on `wherever_you_send.php` you would do like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['prop1'])){
  $results = []; 
  $results['returnProp'] = $_GET['prop1']; // add results like this
  echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

By the way, the whole reason you usually use AJAX is so you don't have to refresh the page... but, if you must `location.reload(true)` in JavaScript. Remove the `true` argument to preserve cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json_encode` your `$response` and serve that to the browser. You do not redirect in php when using ajax. It won't work.

PHP:

```
    if ($result) {
        $response = array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => $this->localization->lang('success', array('name' => $this->localization->lang('task_tickets'))),
            'redirect_url' => base_url() . '/some/url'
        );
        //$this->redirect->back();
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $this->localization->lang('error_update_message', array('name' => $this->localization->lang('task_tickets')))
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
```

JQUERY:

```
function reject(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?= $this->url_generator->current_url() ?>/reject/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                $.growl.notice({message: response.message}); // this message probably won't display due to redirect
                window.location.href = response.redirect_url; // redirect
            } else {
                $.growl.error({message: response.message});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please note: since you want to redirect your success message in jquery probably won't show, or if it does, it will only show for less than a second or so depending on how fast the clients internet is. I would suggest adding a flash message instead, or a prompt with the message so that when the user clicks ok he will be redirected.